# Add Java Applet to Sencha Touch 2

Tags: html, applet, scroll, sencha-touch

I want to add a Java Applet to Sencha Touch 2. Is there an opportunity? For example in `Ext.app.Application` with a config attribute or in `Ext.navigation.View` or somewhere else?

At the moment I have it in the `workflow.html` under the body tag:

```
<body>
    <applet name="MyName" id="MyId" code="main.Main" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;" archive="MyApplet.jar"></applet>
</body>
```

There is also a problem with the applet, there is a white space on the top and then under approximate 50px you can see the application. Because of the lacking px, the complete scroll behavior is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it by adding "position: absolute;" to the style attribute, e.g.:

```
<body>
    <applet name="MyName" id="MyId" code="main.Main" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" archive="MyApplet.jar"></applet>
</body>
```